# Returning partial state

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have a large **json dataset** for products which I call it the **products source of truth**. Using some filtering, I have to filter this *dataset* and return a *subset* of products that match the filter. I can use different filters and it should return a subset from the source of truth. The filters can be (1) products having the keyword 'javascript' in the title (2) products with price greater than $10. I can also add a new product to this source of truth. I can apply filter again and the newly added product may return in the result subset.

All the reducer examples that I saw are returning a state from the previous state. So, in my case if I follow that reducer principle, I can apply a filter on the **products source of truth** and get a new state. Now if I apply another filter, I can apply that only on the new state and not on the source of truth. So, the filter is done on the already filtered products state.

I want the filter to apply on the **original/master products source of truth**. I don't want the filter to be applied on the already filtered state.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Could you make a piece of state called fullData that holds the whole, large JSON dataset, and then your filter could call an action that dispatches a subset of fullData as filteredData (a separate piece of state), perhaps? You could then create a function that renders the fullData if filteredData doesn't exist, otherwise it renders the filteredData. That might not be the most elegant solution, but I think it would work.

Make a 'type' called FILTER_RESULTS, maybe. Then you create an action in your action creator file:

```
export function filterResults(fullData) {
 // javascript here to filter results
 return {
  type: FILTER_RESULTS,
  payload: <variable containing filtered results>
 };
}
```

Then your reducer would have a switch statement that would return action.payload to the filteredData piece of state.

Your action does the filtering, passes the filtered results along to the reducer, and your mapStateToProps allows the component to access your state. Look here: https://github.com/joshuaslate/mern-starter

Comment: Where can that filtering be done? In reducers or the **MapStateToProps** function?

Comment: I revised my answer for clarification, but please see the link I added. It will show you basic examples of how action creators, reducers, and connect work together.

Comment: Your solution proposes to have two different states - master state and sub state. Abhinav's solution is to use only one state and the don't use redux store for the new state. It is a UI concern so manage it in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement the logic of filtering the data, if it's to be done on client sidem in the `component` itself, since it's a `"transient state"`.

Say if you have a `Container` component which has the data and renders following components:

1. `Filter` component - rendering the filter section, where we select such filters.
2. `WorkspaceView` component - rendering the actual view with the data, where we see the data.

Then your `Container` component will filter the data itself based on the `filters` sent by `Filter` component and pass on the data to `WorkspaceView` 


I don't think `Redux` should be used in case of such "temporary" state and should only be used in case of the data being served from backend or something.